# Java Thread Synchronization does not work as expected

Tags: java, multithreading, synchronization

The following is a Java Program demonstrating Threading and Synchronization in Java.

```
    class AB{
    synchronized public void print(String name) {
        for(int i=0;i<5;i++) {
            System.out.println(name+" "+i);
            try {
                Thread.sleep(1000);
            }
            catch(InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}
//extending thread is another way. Usually we use Runnable Interface
class NewThread implements Runnable{
    String name;
    AB obj;
    Thread t;
    NewThread(String name,AB o){
        this.name=name;
        obj=o;
        t=new Thread(this,name);
        t.start();
    }
    
    public void run() {
        obj.print(name);
    }
}

public class ThreadExample {
public static void main(String g[]) {
    AB t=new AB();
    NewThread t1=new NewThread("1",t);
    System.out.println("A");
    NewThread t2=new NewThread("2",t);
    System.out.println("B");
    NewThread t3=new NewThread("3",t);
    System.out.println("C");
    //join is similar to wait for processes. Parent thread(main) waits for children to terminate
    //note that without synchronization, all three threads execute simultaneously.
    try {
    t1.t.join();
    t2.t.join();
    t3.t.join();
    }
    catch(InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    for(int i=0;i<5;i++) {
        System.out.println("main thread"+" "+i);
        try {
            Thread.sleep(1000);
        }
        catch(InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
}
```

The expected output should have been t1 thread output, A, t2, B, t3, C and then main thread. Because of the order in which the print and thread creation statements are present. And also because synchronised keyword has been added to synchronize the threads. But the observed output is as follows:

A,B,C,t1,t3,t2,main

What could be the reason for the deviation between the expected and the observed behavior?
I believe that Java is Synchronous so only after thread t1 is created and printed then system print (A) should work?

Comment: The reason is your expectations are wrong. Why did you expect that?

Comment: If you want a specific order, why are you using threads? and what makes you think they should execute in any specific order?

Comment: Shouldn't the display order depend upon the sequence in which the print statements are present? And the output should have been as expected because of thread synchronisation right?

Comment: No. The display order depends on the order in which they are executed: and as threads execute in parallel, there are no rational grounds for expecting one specific order over any other.

Answer (score 0):

As a user pointed out(thank you, sorry for not responding to your comment), the OS only schedules a thread for execution and does not immediately start the thread(Thread.start()).

The reason that the thread outputs appear after A,B,C in this case is because the for loop (initialization, condition check and then print) seems to add an overhead. So by the time the thread prints a message, A,B,C would have been printed. However if the thread prints only a simple print message like System.out.println(name); then in the output I observed that the thread output appears most of the times like this:  A,t1,B,C,t2,t3 and then main.

Finally, since the OS schedules the threads, one cannot expect the same order of threads to be scheduled every time. This is what I observed when I executed the program several times. For simple print message, the above mentioned output appeared  many times. Some times the output was perfectly as expected. But with the for loop, the thread output almost always appears after A,B,C.